# Нужно ускорить что-либо

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация

Представим что есть такой скрипт

```
for number in range(100000):
    print(number)
```

И мне нужно ускорить работу этого скрипта любым способом

Comment: Могу посоветовать вам JIT-компилятор [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) и [pypy](https://numba.pydata.org/).

Comment: Закомментируйте вторую строчку. :) Серьёзно, вывод в терминал занимает довольно много времени.

Comment: @GrAnd кстати да, примерно .00001 сек. Но что тогда делать в цикле?

Comment: Насчёт numba он не особо совместим с python3.9. pypy не знал, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: @Penggrin хорошо)

Comment: @Ma3rX ты кстати указал неверную ссылку на pypy

Comment: @Penggrin вполне совместим. Максимум, что может произойти - ошибка `Runtime error 001`, а это как раз из-за того, что numba создан для версии Python 3.7.1

Comment: @Ma3rX Ну не знаю, я однажды пытался использовать f-string'и вместе с numba, вылетела ошибка. В интернете увидел что numba не особо совместим с python3.9

Comment: Ускорять надо прямо эту конкретную программу (тогда учитывается время загрузки интерпретатора) или только сам цикл (без времени загрузки)?

Comment: Пишите в файл и всё будет моментально работать )

Comment: @CrazyElf, numpy грузится дольше чем эта штука печатает в файл.

Comment: можно вместо скрипта взять готовую последовательность A001477

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy `Numba` долго запрягает, но быстро едет! ))  Но тут, конечно, нужно отделить вычисления от ввода-вывода. `Numpy` и `Numba` - для ускорения вычислений, а не для ввода-вывода )

Comment: Почему серьёзные вопросы оптимизации рассматриваются на примере бесполезной херни? Надо бы пример ближе к делу привести...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам на самом деле нужно ускорить именно этот код

```
for number in range(100000):
    print(number)
```

то Python и его модули врядли здесь вам смогут помочь, т.к. печать на экран занимает для 100 строк 99.89% времени:

```
In [72]: %%timeit
    ...: for number in range(100):
    ...:     print(number)
...
1.02 ms ± 467 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

теперь тот же цикл, но без печати на экран:

```
In [73]: %%timeit
    ...: for number in range(100):
    ...:     # print(number)
    ...:     pass
    ...:
1.1 µs ± 28.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

PS если мне не изменяет память Numba не поддерживает функцию `print()` ;)

---

Если хотите заняться **микро**-оптимизацией - можно использовать `list comprehension` вместо обычного цикла:

```
_ = [print(i) for i in range(100000)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Эта функция на моём компьютере исполняется `0.015` с. Стандартный вывод перенаправлен в `/dev/null`:

```
def pr_3():
    print('\n'.join(map(str, range(100000))))
```

Оригинальная функция тратит `0.042` с:

```
def pr():
    for number in range(100000):
        print(number)
```

Я пробовал всевозможные вариации с `numpy`, быстрее ничего не нашел.

Забыл baseline, работает `0.000035` с:

```
def pr_4():
    print('''0
1
...
99998
99999''')
```